# default sftp server in debian 9 stretch

Tags: sftp

Please, what is default sftp server in debian 9 stretch after clean system installation? 
I wanted to configure proftd as I thought it is proftpd but I found out there is something other installed. Many thanks

Comment: proftd is ftps, sftp is implemented by the SSH daemon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default Debian 9 SFTP server is provided by OpenSSH's ssh server `sshd`. To disable it type `sudo systemctl stop sshd && sudo systemctl disable sshd`. HOWEVER if you do this you will also be disabling your SSH server. FTP and SFTP are two different protocols and should be able to exist on the same machine on separate ports.

EDIT: Jeff's comment on my answer is also a good suggestion to more specifically disable SFTP. In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` disable the line `Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server` by putting a `#`(hash sign) in front of it like so, `# Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to remove the Subsystem line from sshd_config?

Comment: in debian you can just uninstall `openssh-sftp-server` package.