# Why do I not need to start an SFTP Server ( why does SSH automatically start SFTP )?

Tags: ssh, openssh, sftp, ftp

## Question

When I start SSH server, my Debian automatically start the SFTP server as well - why is it design in such way?

Environment:

- Linux 5.10.0-14-amd64 Debian 5.10.113-1 (2022-04-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux
- ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server

## Background

Today I realized:

- when I want to handle http requests, I start a web server - Apache(2), Node.js, etc.
- when I want to handle SSH, I start an SSH server
- when I want to handle SFTP... Debian already started SFTP server for me

So I researched, and according to this post [378313/default-sftp-server-in-debian-9-stretch](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/378313/default-sftp-server-in-debian-9-stretch), I found out SFTP is started as "part of (Open)SSH" which makes perfect sense but also feels strange for reasons such as separation of concerns.

Unlike Windows, I have never felt Debian doing something unexpected or extra on my behalf. But today I felt it - after all I said `systemctl restart ssh`, not `systemctl restart ssh-and-also-ftp` (the latter command is made-up).

As I am new to Unix/Linux and its philosophy, I would appreciate if there are any good explanations for this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although SFTP is not part of the [extensible core SSH protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4251), it is built-in to at least one of the the common SSH implementations (OpenSSH) and therefore can be considered to be a [standard component](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-02).

You can disable the functionality on the server if it's not required by changing `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` so that you remove the `Subsystem` line corresponding to the `sftp-server`.

For example, this line defines an external `sftp-server` utility to handle the SFTP service:

```
Subsystem sftp-server
```

This line defines an internal implementation of the SFTP service:

```
Subsystem internal-sftp
```

Removing or commenting out the `Subsystem` line will disable the SFTP service entirely.

```
# Subsystem …
```

Remember that tools such as `rsync` (if it's installed) and versions of `scp` will still function, though, so disabling SFTP will not of itself prevent users from transferring files between client and server. (Older versions of `scp` will work independently of SFTP. Newer versions use SFTP but can be forced to use the older protocol with the `-O` flag.) There are also "trivial" solutions such as `ssh remoteHost cat somefile > local_copy_of_somefile` to consider.

Comment: This solution (removing or commenting out the `Subsystem` line of `sshd_config`) will not work in Debian based systems including Ubuntu because these have a compiled-in default of `Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server` (see `man sshd_config`). For these systems, see my answer.

Comment: @Juergen you and I must have different versions of Debian. I have just retested (this time on bullseye) and if I comment the `Subsystem …` line the service is disabled. The precise error returned to the client is _`subsystem request failed on channel 0`_

Comment: My experience was from an old Ubuntu 16 system where commenting out the subsystem line, reloading the `ssh` service and killing the `sftp-server` process caused it to respawn. Added some details to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Oddly, the accepted answer here does not address the question asked.

> why is it design in such way?

The SFTP Server in openssh is not a conventional daemon/server. An instance is run on demand when a ssh connection requesting SFTP starts.

ssh can do lots of things - designing it this way means that there's no overhead from the sftp-server when people are using ssh for other stuff. Similarly ssh is often used for providing a remote terminal session but it doesn't implement its own shell.

In addition to being more conservative with resources, it also simplifies development by making the system modular.

Comment: The SFTP server is built directly into OpenSSH SSH server (`sshd`) since 2009. See https://serverfault.com/q/660160/168875

Comment: @MartinPrikryl but symcbean is correct in that SFTP is/was not part of the original core SSH protocol. I've amended my own answer to highlight this

Comment: @ChrisDavies I was not questioning whether SFTP is part of SSH standard (I do not even thing that this answer claims that [or the opposite]). I just reacted to the "resources" and "modular system" claims – while those have probably been valid decades ago (when `sftp-server` was separate), they are not valid anymore. And even when `sftp-server` was separate binary, it was a never separate deamon, so it has imo nothing to do with the OPs question.

Answer (score 0):

To disable the built-in `sftp` server of `sshd` on Debian based systems including Ubuntu, it is not sufficient to remove or comment out the `Subsystem` line of `sshd_config` because these systems have a compiled-in default of `Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server` (see `man sshd_config`).

I had success disabling SFTP with this line in `sshd_config` instead in an yet old Ubuntu 16 system:

```
Subsystem sftp /bin/false
```

followed by `systemctl reload ssh; killall sftp-server`.

Citation from `man sshd_config` (same text in Ubuntu 16 and Ubuntu 22):
"Note that the Debian openssh-server package sets several options as standard in /etc/ssh/sshd_config which are not the default in sshd(8):
(...)
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server"